# Typescript union type for functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a problem with understanding of Typescript type describing my validation functions.
These are the types of functions that I use with my code:

```
type ValidationFunctionType = {
    fieldName: string;
    fields: string;
};

type MaxYearType = ValidationFunctionType & { fieldValue: Date; args: { maxYear: Date } };

type MinLengthType = ValidationFunctionType & {
    fieldValue: string;
    args: { minLength: number };
};

type MinNumberType = ValidationFunctionType & {
    fieldValue: number;
    args: { minNumber: number };
};
```

Then I create a union type for all the functions:

```
export type ValidationFunctionsType =
    | (({}: MinLengthType) => string)
    | (({}: MinNumberType) => string)
    | (({}: MaxYearType) => string);
```

These are the functions that I use with these function types:

```
const minLength = ({ fieldName, fieldValue, fields, args }: MinLengthType) => {
    return '';
};

const maxYear = ({ fieldName, fieldValue, fields, args }: MaxYearType) => {
    return '';
};

const minNumber = ({ fieldName, fieldValue, fields, args }: MinNumberType) => {
    return '';
};
```

And when I create an array with the above functions and use them in map:

```
const validationFunction: { func: ValidationFunctionsType}[] = [{
    func: minLength
  }, { func: maxYear}];

validationFunction.map(data => data.func({ fieldName: 'adfa', fieldValue: 'asdda', fields: 'sd', args: {
    minLength: 5
  } }));
```

I get the error message for field fieldName:

> (property) fieldValue: never Type 'string' is not assignable to type
> 'never'.(2322) input.tsx(9, 2): The expected type comes from property
> 'fieldValue' which is declared here on type 'ValidationFunctionType &
> { fieldValue: string; args: { minLength: number; }; } & { fieldValue:
> number; args: { minNumber: number; }; } & { fieldValue: Date; args: {
> ...; }; }'

And for args field:

> (property) args: {
> minLength: number; } & {
> minNumber: number; } & {
> maxYear: Date; } Type '{ minLength: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ minLength: number; } & { minNumber: number; } & { maxYear:
> Date; }'.   Property 'minNumber' is missing in type '{ minLength:
> number; }' but required in type '{ minNumber: number; }'.(2322)

Why these types for field args and fieldName are connected with & operator instead of | operator? How to create a type for these functions which will be correct and more generic?

The whole code example in TS playground: [Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBM7CQewHYDECu2AxhjgCrjQC8UA3gLABQAkAGZIQIoBycAthABcUAM7AATkmwBzANxM2HLiOFjJM%20YwC%20mpqEhQAsnAAeATQhxxFAzXjI0pPIRJZsN6ADI6UdpxT2%20EJQACLoELJQVtIqPnymFlbCYcDQWlA6THqURlIAMhAywAAWHlB2iKjobgTETmXeDCx%20XIHBalJyCtGxtFB8%20YXSJcLY%20HwARhDiGZqZjNkGhlLc41PWORUO1Ti1ruQ5jQotAYhBo2vTmsw9wn0D2KuT0xfPM-PzTEQ4Yv2DRcVylAABR9E68AQAGl8SlOCCC0JOImhPQywmW2AKAI8AEpygA%20OgKcQQYD4cTYKAAcipc10jG%202F%208XMlhmNFBMP8EIgiNhbT5-mRUXEMTRRgSbNxBKJLBJZIp1NpTE%20DJ%20wD%20j0u7JBYNhPMFrTOvK5yhRopE4oxT3W0qohKazHl5MpNLpWUYEBMYEw4g1%20mg9iqTj2ThEZSoCgAPiDQVp0f9hqVKHj7aIJJ0cdHY7R47ktW87YSOjIsywY8C4%20jJVYi%20n1NIcfSoFBGb8AG6VRw1FxOO6%20FzCIPd3a9tzhyhaADaAF0gVOmi2W6xB5qsUmmC2tNCwauWYlxFoZ82oJ3tiGxzgAHTxMDAxxwGUPq8r4ic8H8YJUuAoVhwKmGnC5zUnAIgoGgAGmigsRUmBkG3LKS5rkMIxQAArJuGQZDiTZAA)

## UPDATE

What I want to achieve in this example is to have a correctly designed type for all functions used for validation.

This type seems to work for Typescript:

```
type ValidationFunctionType = ({fieldName, fields, fieldValue, args}: MinLengthType | MinNumberType | MaxYearType) => string;
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vnwfqp?file=index.ts)
But I'm not sure if it is the correct solution. Every function needs validation of fieldName and args type at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.func({ fieldName: 'adfa', fieldValue: 'asdda', fields: 'sd', args: {
  minLength: 5
}}
```

You're passing in values here that make sense if the function is expecting a `MinLengthType`. But since `data.func` is a `ValidationFunctionsType`, the type doesn't actually show that that's the expected data. The function might instead be expecting a `MinNumberType` or a `MaxYearType`, and the object you've passed would be an error for those, hence typescript shows an error.

Since there's 3 possible functions you might be dealing with, typescript will only allow you to pass in values that match all 3 functions. Ie, you can pass in the intersection of all 3 types: `MinLengthType & MinNumberType & MaxYearType`. Unfortunately, that intersection is impossible to obey because it requires mutually exclusive things like `fieldValue` being a `string`, a `number`, and a `Date` simultaneously. So there is no way to legally call `data.func`.

As for how to fix this... I'm not really sure what you're hoping to achieve from this code, so i may need more details. If you receive a function that expects, say, a `MaxYearType`, what do you want to do? Call the function with some alternate data; not call it at all; something else? Also, how do you intend to identify which function variant you have?

Comment: Basically I want to have an object fo every field in form which looks like: 
`year: {
  label: 'Year',
  validationData: [{ validationFunction: maxYear, args: { maxYear: new Date() } }],
  fieldType: 'date',
  transformData: value => new Date(value)
},`

And validate it with functions inserted in validation data array.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a classic case of [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).

In your case, you should implement the signatures:

```js
function validate(fieldName: string, fields: string, fieldValue: Date; args: { maxYear: Date }):string;

function validate(fieldName: string, fields: string, fieldValue: string; args: { maxYear: number }):string;
```

Finally, your implementation of `validate` should support every case - you can use [type guard](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-type-guards-typescript/) for type checking

Reference for function overloading:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

Comment: I don't think these would be the desired solution for me. I still want to use distinct function names like minLength etc..